# why addeventlistener works only for one element in for loop?

Tags: javascript, electron

i'm using electron and i'm facing a problem right now. I use **fs** to get files from my pc folder. Then each element is displayed to html page. Also, there is delete button to delete this element. Every delete button has **id equal to element name**. For example there is **helloworld** element in the list. So it's delete button **has id helloworld**. Then I getElementById - get that titles and apply event listener to buttons. But it works only for the last element. Why? If I log all the objects to console, it displays them all, as It should. But event listener works only for one.
Thank you!

```
for(let projectFile of data)
{
    fs.readFile(save_path+"\\"+projectFile, function(err, data)
    {           
        if(data != null)
         {
             let presentation_Object = JSON.parse(data.toString());

             document.getElementById('allProjects').innerHTML = document.getElementById('allProjects').innerHTML + "<button class='b wh project-box-danger btn'>"+presentation_Object.title+"<a id='"+presentation_Object.title+"'"+" href='#/'><i class='far fa-trash-alt pull-right'></i></a></button>"; // Add button and delete button with id equal to button value
         }

        var projectD = JSON.parse(data.toString()); // it works well, every object is initialized

        document.getElementById(projectD.title).addEventListener('click', function(){
            console.log(projectD.title + " is deleted"); // works only for the last element
        });


     });
}
```

Works only for **title** object - the last one

[image]

Comment: replacing the html, removes the event handlers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach bypassing the content rewriting:

```
if(data != null) {

  let presentation_Object = JSON.parse(data);

  var div = document.createElement('div')

  div.innerHTML = "<button class='b wh project-box-danger btn'>"+presentation_Object.title+"<a id='"+presentation_Object.title+"'"+" href='#/'><i class='far fa-trash-alt pull-right'></i>TEST</a></button>"

  document.getElementById('allProjects').appendChild(div)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The comment clarify your issue.
In any case you may consider to use [.closest('button')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) (for compatibility you may use the polyfill defined in the documentation) and you may move your click event handler outside of the for loop:

```js
for(var i=1;i<10;i++) {
  document.getElementById('allProjects').innerHTML = document.getElementById('allProjects').innerHTML +
          "<button class='b wh project-box-danger btn'>title"+i+"<a id='title"+i+"'"+" href='#/'><i class='far fa-trash-alt pull-right'></i></a></button>";
}
document.querySelector('#allProjects').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  var p = e.target.closest('button'); // if a button ele or child...
  if (!!p && p.tagName == 'BUTTON') {
      console.log(p.textContent + " is deleted"); 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>


<div id="allProjects">

</div>
```